# DataFrame.sort_values only looks at first digit rather then entire number

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this,

```
    del Ticker  Open Interest
0   1   SPY     20,996,893
1   3   IWM     7,391,074
2   5   EEM     6,545,445
...
47  46  MU      1,268,256
48  48  NOK     1,222,759
49  50  ET      1,141,467
```

I want it to go in order from the lowest number to greatest with `df['del']`, but when I write `df.sort_values('del')` I get

```
    del Ticker
0   1   SPY
29  10  BAC
5   11  GE
```

It appears do do it based on the first number rather than go in order? Am I using the correct code or do I need to completely change it?

Comment: del is probably a string rather than an int, check the dtypes

Comment: @sim That's a good point. Try either checking the `dtype` of `del` or explicitly convert it to `int`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have numbers as type string you can do:

add leading zeros to the string numbers which will allow for ordering of the string

```
df["del"] = df["del"].map(lambda x: x.zfill(10))
df = df.sort_values('del')
```

or convert the type to integer

```
df["del"] = df["del"].astype('int') # as recommended by Alex.Kh in comment
#df["del"] = df["del"].map(int) # my initial answer
df = df.sort_values('del')
```

I also noticed that del seems to be sorted in the same way your index is sorted, so you even could do:

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
```

to go from lowest to highest you can explicitly `.sort_values('del', ascending=True)`

Comment: Instead of using the `map()` ,I think it is better to use `astype()`. For ex, `df.del=df.del.astype('int')` (I believe it less computationally-costly)

Comment: You might be right, would be interesting to see the actual difference. I updated my answer based on your comment. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Just for the reference, I tested both ways out and `map()` was definitely slower. For a series `pd.Series(list('12345')*10000)` `astype(int)` took `3.39 ms ± 40.8 µs per loop` while `map()` took `13.7 ms ± 144 µs per loop`. As far as I remember, `astype` is a vectorized function while `map` applies the function to each element consequently, so no wonder it is faster

Comment: Ah, makes sense then. Thank you for clearing that up.